# Implicit operator overload without redefine type

Tags: c#

I need overload the implicit operator, but i need modify own value, not create a new value for the type.

```
public abstract class AbstractScriptableValue<T>//this generic abstract class
{
    [SerializeField] protected T value;//internal value

    protected T previusValue;//previus internal value, for know if the value changes

    public T Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;

            if (!this.value.Equals(previusValue))//if the value change
            {
                previusValue = this.value;//update
                OnValueChanged();//and very importantan!!! notify for a change
            }
        }
    }

    public Action OnValueChanged;
}


public class ValueInt : AbstractScriptableValue<int>
{
    public static implicit operator ValueInt(int argValueA)
    {
         this.Value = argValueA;//error here, because i need evaluate the previus value for notify if it changes, then i set the value for the property .Value, if in this point i create a new value, then i cant notify if it changes.
         return this;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helpme to search a solution that permits me notify the value change.

Comment: An operator in C# **must** return a new value. It is also `static` so `this` is not allowed. Can you elaborate on what you want to do?

Comment: You're trying to use `this` in a static context, that won't work. You're using = on a declaration, not an actual object/instance (that behaviour cannot be changed). Therefore you cannot _just change_ a value.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what kind of syntax that would be enabled/possible by whatever change you would want to make.

Comment: Think of it this way how would `(ValueInt)5` updated an existing `ValueInt` and if so which one?

Comment: In which situations is this intended to be used?

Comment: You need to set the current `this.value` to the previous before setting it to the the new value.

Comment: If you have an instance of a `ValueInt` and you want to change it's value just do `myValueInt.Value = 5;`.  There is no way that `ValueInt x = 5;` can do anything other than create a new `ValueInt` (unless you make it update a static singleton `ValueInt` and return that)

Answer (score 1):

The `implicit` operator overload method is `static`, so there is no instance you could access. Instead, create a new instance of your class and then access the property:

```
public static implicit operator ValueInt(int argValueA)
{
    var result = new ValueInt(); // or whatever constructor you want to call
    result.Value = argValueA;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I know this solution, but no works for notify a new value, because it create a new value instead. i updated my question for more details.

Comment: @Glorfindel Can an answer get invalidated on this site by an edit in OP?